# How to validate that a property with a DATE-TIME value must have a TZID parameter?

Tags: icalendar

Section [3.2.19](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19) of RFC 5545 says that a property with a DATE-TIME value must specify a TZID parameter in this situation:

```
The parameter [TZID] MUST be specified on properties with a DATE-TIME value if the DATE-TIME is not either a UTC or a "floating" time.
```

The DTSTART property has a DATE-TIME value. Here is an instance:

DTSTART:19970714T133000

Is that a valid property with a "floating" time? Or, is it an invalid property  with a "floating" time that erroneously forgot to include the TZID parameter?

When validating an iCalendar file, how do I distinguish between a valid property with a value that is a "floating" time versus an invalid property with a value that is a "floating" time and erroneously forgot to include the TZID parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When validating an iCalendar stream, there is nothing to distinguish. It is always a floating time.

When constructing an iCalendar stream on the other hand, one should

1. first understand the 3 types defined at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 ,
2. then decide which one is the most appropriate in their application specific context.
3. finally, based upon 2 (i.e. choice between UTC, local with tz or floating), apply the rule that you referenced in your post.

Please note that client support for floating time is generally poor and unpredictable so you should avoid generating it if you can.

Comment: Thank you arnaudq. My takeaway of your message is that it is impossible to validate an iCalendar file. Specifically, it is impossible to validate whether properties with floating date-time values are valid. That strikes me as a bug in the iCalendar specification. I should be able to validate whether or not an iCalendar file is valid. Do you agree?

Comment: Well, it is just a convention. The convention adopted to distinguish between the 3 date time format is the presence of the TZID parameter and the Z suffix in the value. I guess the convention could have been to have more fine grained VALUE parameter (e.g. DATE, UTCDATETIME, TZIDDATETIME, FLOATINGDATETIME). In practice though, I have not seen many cases where this turned out to be an issue. So I would not consider this really as a bug.